# Multiple link refs on one row from html .db file

Tags: python, html, flask

I have a flask app on pythonanywhere where I am displaying the contents of a .db file on an html coded page. What is happening is that the column that i have the href on puts it on every row instead of just one row in that column. In short I want each column to take me to a different link. My question is probably not very clear so I will provide a link to the site below as well as the code.
[flask_app](http://ethankbdca.pythonanywhere.com/forums)

This is the flask route:

```
@app.route('/forums')
def forums():
    conn = sqlite3.connect("/home/Ethankbdca/mysite/forum.db")
    c = conn.cursor()
    sql = "SELECT Forums, Description, blank FROM Home Order By Forums"
    c.execute(sql)
    allforums = []
    for row in c.fetchall():
        tup = (row[0],row[1],row[2])
        allforums.append(tup)
conn.close()
return render_template('forumhome.html', allforums=allforums)
```

This is the html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css"/>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1 align="center">Share Your Code</h1>
<table width="90%">
   {% for x in allforums:  %}
   <tr>
        <td width=5%><a href='/python_forum' >{{ x[0] }}</a></td>
        <td width=50%> {{ x[1] }} </td>
   </tr>
   {% endfor %}
</table><br/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: **TYPO** alert: it's a **column** - not a "collum" ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand the question. Use the id of the database entry to retrieve the entry in another route.

```
@app.route('/forum/')
def forum_index():
    conn = sqlite3.connect("/home/Ethankbdca/mysite/forum.db")
    c = conn.cursor()
    sql = "SELECT id, forums, description, blank FROM home ORDER BY forums"
    c.execute(sql)
    records = [(row[0],row[1],row[2]) for row in c.fetchall()]
    conn.close()
    return render_template('forum_index.html', items=records)

@app.route('/forum/<int:item_id>')
def forum_show(item_id):
    conn = sqlite3.connect("/home/Ethankbdca/mysite/forum.db")
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute("SELECT * FROM home WHERE id == " + str(item_id))
    record = tuple(c.fetchone())
    conn.close()
    return render_template('forum_show.html', item=record)
```

layout.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', 'main.css') }}" />
  </head>
  <body>
  {% block content %}{% endblock %}
  </body>
</html>
```

forum_index.html

```
{% extends 'layout.html' %}
{% block content %}
<h1 align="center">Share Your Code</h1>
<table width="90%">
    {% for item in items:  %}
    <tr>
        <td width=5%><a href="{{ url_for('forum_show', item_id=item[0]) }}" >{{ item[1] }}</a></td>
        <td width=50%>{{ item[2] }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
{% endblock %}
```

forum_show.html

```
{% extends 'layout.html' %}
{% block content %}
    <h1 align="center">Is This Your Code?</h1>
    <div>
        <h4>{{ item[1] }}</h4>
        <code><pre>{{ item[2] }}</pre></code>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Familiarize yourself with the CRUD concept, it will help you with the order within your application.

It would help you if you use an ORM like ["flask_sqlalchemy"](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.3/), otherwise look [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/patterns/sqlite3/).

["flask-blueprint"](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/blueprints/) structures your application into different individual modules. Very helpful.

You found your mistake [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55360672/i-am-making-a-flask-app-using-pythonanywhere-and-i-am-getting-an-error-when-subm/55363930)?
Have fun!

Comment: Oh sorry. I just saw your code. I guess a facebook account works if you are still open to that.